# how to add a background to Prefixicon flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been searching for a way to create a **Prefixicon** with a background. How to achieve that?

[see that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzvrD.png)

Comment: Prefix icon takes a widget as a parameter, you can try wrapping that icon with container.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by @Rashid Wassan, we can use a `Container` wrapper to define a `prefixIcon` with a background color. Below you can find an example:

```
prefixIcon: Container(
  color: Colors.red, // background color
  child: Icon(Icons.search), // icon
)
```